# Maven <Export-Package> issues in two dependent projects using Java when using Reflection API classes

Tags: java, maven, reflection

I'm working as Backend developer, I'm using Java 1.6, JDBC and Angular JS.

From past 5 days i'm experiencing a strange behaviour in my Java Code.

Here is the problem description:

I have Two Maven projects
1. A - A uses internally B classes so A is dependent on B
2. B - B having few java source files.. These i'm exporting using  tag

These projects are there from almost 3years and working as expected.

Problem: I created a new Source file in Maven Project B in a package which already exists in Project B.

I'm using Java Reflection API to get the values using below code.

```
 VLANService vlanServiceObj =  vlanServiceArr[i];

    /**vlanServiceObj This class has almost 50-100 methods i don't want use like below
     *vlanServiceObj.getName();
     *vlanServiceObj.getAddress();
     *vlanServiceObj.getSalary();
     *.
     *.
     *.
     *etc
     */

        Class cls = vlanServiceObj.getClass();

        java.lang.reflect.Method[] serviceOrderAllMethods = cls.getDeclaredMethods();

        int allMethodsCount = serviceOrderAllMethods.length;

            for(int i=0;i<allMethodsCount; i++) {

               java.lang.reflect.Method method = serviceOrderAllMethods[i];

               if("java.lang.String".equalsIgnoreCase(method.getReturnType().getName()) 
                     && method.getName().toUpperCase().startsWith("GET")) {
                            try {
                                parameterValueMap.put(method.getName().substring(3, method.getName().length()), (String)method.invoke(cls));
                            }catch (Exception e) {
                                System.out.println("Doesn't have access to getter method of Beans class :: "+cls.getName());
                            }
                        }
                    }

    class name : ResponseProecssor.java
    package name : com.tl.services.parser

                        I'm using Export in Project A like below
                        <Export-Package>                            
                             com.tl.services.parser.*
                        </Export-Package>

                        In Project B i'm importing the same packe like below
                        <Import-Package>
                            com.tl.services.parser.*
                        </Import-Package>
```

As package(com.tl.services.parser) is already exported to jar i have not done any changes to POM.xml and my new file is working as expected.

I'm invoking this new processor from Project A.

The movement i include java.lang.reflect package in my import statement i'm getting NoClassDefFoundError in Project A where i'm using Project B class(ResponseProecssor)

When i remove java.lang.reflect(Reflection API) code execution is going to my new class and everything works.

Are there any issues with Reflection API using with Maven or accessing from other project do i have to export package?

Thanks in Advance.
Arshad Patan